# stringWithFormat, dateFromString, & stringFromDate not working

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

I am trying to display the time difference from `UIDatePicker` input and real world time in an `IBOutlet` label in the form `dd:hh:mm:ss`. I have my `NSLog` displaying the correct information but I am having a hard time getting the same data to be displayed in my label.
As of right now, I get nothing displayed in my UILabel but the correct data is in the NSLog.
When I change

```
[self.formatter stringFromDate:timeDif];
```

to

```
[self.formatter stringFromDate:selected];
```

the current DatePicker selection time is displayed (which is not what I want) but the NSLog still displays the time difference correctly. I know it is something wrong with my formatting sequence or something but I have not been able to see where I am going wrong.

```
- (IBAction)displayDate:(id)sender {

    NSDate *timeDif = [self.formatter dateFromString:self.string];
    NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *selected = [picker date];

    self.formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [self.formatter setDateFormat:@"dd:hh:mm:ss"];

    [picker setDate:selected animated:YES];

    self.label.text = [self.formatter stringFromDate:timeDif];

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents *dateComparisonComponents = [gregorian components:unitFlags
                                                              fromDate:todaysDate
                                                                toDate:selected
                                                               options:NSWrapCalendarComponents];

    NSInteger days = [dateComparisonComponents day];
    NSInteger hours = [dateComparisonComponents hour];
    NSInteger minutes = [dateComparisonComponents minute];
    NSInteger seconds = [dateComparisonComponents second];

    dateComponents.day = days;
    dateComponents.hour = hours;
    dateComponents.minute = minutes;
    dateComponents.second = seconds;

    self.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1d:%1d:%1d:%1d",
                                              dateComparisonComponents.day,
                                              dateComparisonComponents.hour,
                                              dateComparisonComponents.minute,
                                              dateComparisonComponents.second];

     NSLog(@"%1d:%1d:%1d:%1d",
                             dateComparisonComponents.day,
                             dateComparisonComponents.hour,
                             dateComparisonComponents.minute,
                             dateComparisonComponents.second);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an awful lot of extra and needless code. Just do this:

```
- (IBAction)displayDate:(id)sender {
    NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *selected = [picker date];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit |NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *dateComparisonComponents = [gregorian components:unitFlags
                                                              fromDate:todaysDate
                                                                toDate:selected
                                                               options:NSWrapCalendarComponents];

    NSInteger days = [dateComparisonComponents day];
    NSInteger hours = [dateComparisonComponents hour];
    NSInteger minutes = [dateComparisonComponents minute];
    NSInteger seconds = [dateComparisonComponents second];

    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld:%02ld:%02ld:%02ld",
                                              days,
                                              hours,
                                              minutes,
                                              seconds];
}
```

In your original code, `self.formatter` won't even be set the first time the code is run. This means that `timeDif` will be `nil` the first time. You also get the picker's date and then set the picker's date to the same value. No reason for that. And you make use of `dateComponents` for no known reason. And lastly, what is `self.string` for?

Comment: Holy crap!! that makes so much more sense! Im extremely new and extremely self taught so showing me that really helps me analyze my code and see how you can simplify the workings of all the components and functions in it to achieve the same result.

Comment: BTW - I just made a small update. Look at the new string format. This will give you the hours, minutes, and seconds so they are always 2 digits with a leading zero if needed.

Comment: I do need that, thanks! But when I updated my code, I get like 10 leading zeros.

Comment: I think the problem is you had `1d` (one dee) instead of `ld` (ell dee). Now it should be `02ld` (zero two ell dee). Read up on string format specifiers to see what can be done.

Comment: gotcha! I will definitely. Thanks again for the help. Showing me a better way was helpful beyond any books or videos.

Comment: One more quick question. How would I go about making a timer that counts down in seconds using the data that I have now? I've created a IBAction to start the timer but don't know how to fill out the refreshLable method that I had set up before as `-(void)refreshLabel
{
    NSDate *selected = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[picker date] timeIntervalSince1970] - 1];
 [picker setDate:selected animated:YES];
 self.label.text = [self.formatter stringFromDate:selected];
}`